# Cannot complete regex replacement by line in Php or Notepad++

Tags: php, regex

190 PALMER RD, HARMONY
MLS® 201512263 $239,900
2 ACRES/HEATED DBL GARAGE/HEAT PUMP
http://goo.gl/tVWDan

I want the above first line '190 PALMER RD, HARMONY' replaced with : `<p style="color: #EF2F48">   <b>  190 PALMER RD, HARMONY </b>      </p>`  using regex in PHP.

I used the following code. But doesn't work. Please help.

(^[0-9].*)  - `<p style="color: #EF2F48">   <b>  \1 </b>      </p>`

I want the above second line 'MLS® 201512263 $239,900' replaced with : `<p> MLS® 201512263  &nbsp;&nbsp; $239,900 </p>`  using regex.

I used the following code. But works.

`(MLS®[0-9]*) (\$[0-9,]+) - <p> \1  &nbsp;&nbsp; \2 </p>`

And I want the third line select by regex. I am not sure. I want like this. `<p style="color: #000">   2 ACRES/HEATED DBL GARAGE/HEAT PUMP    </p>`

Fourth line I selected like this way and replaced.

`(http:*.*) - <p><a class="ui-link" style="color: blue;"href="\1" target="_blank">\1</a></p>`

Please help me.
Manoj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following script:

```
$rx = '/^([^\n]+)\s*([^\n]+) (\$[^\n]+)\s*([^\n]+)\s*([^\n]+)$/sim';
$replacement = '<p style="color: #EF2F48"><b>$1</b></p><p>$2&nbsp;&nbsp$3</p> <p style="color: #000">$3</p> <p><a class="ui-link" style="color: blue;"href="$4" target="_blank">$5</a></p>';

$subject = ".... your test data ....";

$result = preg_replace($rx, $replacement, $subject);
```

Result:

```
<p style="color: #EF2F48"><b>190 PALMER RD, HARMONY</b></p>
<p>MLS® 201512263&nbsp;&nbsp$239,900</p>
<p style="color: #000">$239,900</p> 
<p>
<a class="ui-link" style="color: blue;"href="2 ACRES/HEATED DBL GARAGE/HEAT PUMP" target="_blank">
http://goo.gl/tVWDan</a>
</p>
```

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nR5oI5/3) here

Comment: Please help: I need to insert : &nbsp;&nbsp; between MLS® 201512263 and $239,900